# Customize facebook share content

Tags: seo

I have a WordPress website and where I want to set the custom title, description and image for each URL so that when someone share the URL than they see the content and image which is I predefine. Is it possible? I tried couple of plugin but stuck with it more and more. Anybody can tell me how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

For SEO, I have used the [Wordpress SEO by Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) which allows you to do that on a previous project to great effect.

For Facebook to read the title, description and images for sharing, Opengraph tags have to be generated.  For more about opengraph tags, refer to the Facebook Developer Guide on [using proper opengraph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags).  The Yoast SEO plugin does generate the relevant opengraph tags for sharing.

Specifically the Yoast plugin changelog enhancements include:

- Added Facebook / OpenGraph title input and Google+ title input and image upload field to Social tab.
- Added Facebook / OpenGraph title input for the homepage on SEO -> Social settings page.
- Changed Facebook / OpenGraph default image and homepage image input fields to use the media uploader.